# Angular2: Better way of creating dynamic testing module

Tags: unit-testing, angular, testbed

in our angular2 application we have create a few modules. e.g. appModule, componentModule etc. appModule is our top level module.

While writing our unit test we are create TestBed where we provide individual components as we need. This makes our test runs faster. However, it introduces an issue where whenever anyone adds a new component, it fails all tests until we include the same in testBed creation.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Can you post code or create a complete example reproducing your problem?